# Will the onload event fire later if I use setTimeout to delay some resource load?

Tags: javascript

I am just wondering, if I use setTimeout to delay the executing of loading external images, scripts, will the `Onload` event fire later?

If I set the delay to a very huge number, will the `Onload` event never fire?

Comment: Don't rely on `setTimeout` to load a resource. Use a promise instead. The browser has an API called `fetch` for this very purpose --- A large timeout doesn't necessarily mean never, but to a user they might as well be the same

Comment: Thanks, but I am just wondering how `Onload` event works with special cases.

Comment: Why not try it and find out? Then you could add a [mcve] to the question to show us?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to load external resource with delays? you can use `setTimeout ` and then append the script, image in the html section

Comment: Try this one: ` setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.innerHTML +=(``<img id="bullet" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/194a1798-8f9f-4c5c-b888-d5ab8f60b5fd%2Fbullet.png?v=1627145599587" onload="console.log('loaded images')">``)
        },5000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I set the delay to a very huge number, will the Onload event never fire?

No the `load` event of the `window` will fire as soon as all dependent resources (those that are not marked for deferred or lazy loading) that are currently in the DOM (after the DOM is fully parsed) are loaded.

Otherwise, the `load` event would never fire if there is a script on the page that potentially could change the DOM at any time in the future.

> if I use, `setTimeout` to delay the executing of loading external images, scripts, will the Onload event fire later?

If you add an element with a timeout to the DOM and the `load` has not fired yet, then the `load` event might wait also until that resource is loaded.